# Does exist natural numbers $m, b, q$ with the following conditions

Tags: number-theory

Suppose that $n,N$ are integer such that: $n\ge 2$ , $N\ge 2^{n}-1$.

Does  exist natural numbers $m, b, q$  with the following conditions:

- $m, b$
  are coprime.
- $q$ is a power of a prime number.
- The number of distinct prime factors $m$ be $n$.
- The number of distinct prime factors $b$ be $N$.
- $${q^{m}-1\over q-1}\mid b , \,\,\,\,\text{ and }\,\,\,\ b\mid q(q^{m}-1)$$

Comment: Any reason you're interested in this particular set of relations? It seems quite unmotivated. Anyway, it appears you're asking whether $q^m-1$ can have lots more distinct prime factors than $m$ has. I'm sure $2^p-1$ can have an unbounded number of distinct prime factors, even if $p$ is prime (but I'm also sure no one has been able to prove it).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, at least one instance of this occurs. Just to give one example, $n=2$, $N=8$, $m=99$, $b=2^{99}-1=7\cdot23\cdot73\cdot89\cdot199\cdot153649\cdot599479\cdot33057806959$, $q=2$.

Comment: note that $n,N$ are predetermined.

Comment: OK, so, I've shown that for $n=2$, $N=8$, there exist $m,b,q$. What do you want? Do you want to know, for which $n$ and $N$ do $m,b,q$ exist, and for which $n$ and $N$ do $m,b,q$ not exist? Have you done any calculations to get you own examples? Have you proved that there are $n,N$ for which $m,b,q$ don't exist? I'm doing my best to answer your question – you're not helping by not answering mine.

Comment: My question is : for each $n,N$ that are predetermined ,  Does exist natural numbers $m,b,q$?

Comment: OK, so, I've shown one example, which is one more than you've shown. Do you know any others? Can you answer my questions?

Comment: I do not understand your question, but now you have found an answer to this problem in a special case. Is this idea can be extended to solve the problem?

Comment: My questions: Is there any reason for your interest in this question? Have you found any of your own examples? Have you found any $n,N$ for which you can prove there are no examples?